# sails 1.x inserting 3-party middleware with custom route

Tags: express, sails.js

In sails 0.12 the follow could be used to map a route (/api) to an API as middleware, in http.js.

```
// sails 0.12
module.exports.http = {
    customMiddleware: function (app) {
        let kue = require('kue');
        let kue_queue = kue.createQueue();
        app.use('/api', kue.app);
    }
...
```

How do you do the equivalent of `app.use(someroute,middleware)` in Sails 1.x?

How do I get the express **app** in Sails 1.x?

Is there a simple way to configure the middleware with route in Sails 1.x?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
const myroute = '/api';
const regex = new RegExp('^' + myroute + '(/|$)');
const kue = require('kue');
kue.createQueue();

module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {
    order: ['kue'],

    kue: function (req, res, next) {

      if (req.url.match(regex)) {
        console.log('kue',req.method,req.url);
        req.url = req.url.replace(regex, '/');
        return kue.app(req,res);
      }
      return next();
    }
  },
};
```